# Parse HTMl using JSOUP - Need specific pattern

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to get text between tags and save into some variable, for example:
Here I want to save value `return` which is between `em` tags. Also I need the rest of the text which is in `p` tags, 
`em` tag value is assigned with `return` and 
`p` tag value should return only --> `an item, cancel an order, print a receipt, track your purchases or reorder items.`
if some value is before `em` tag, even that value should be in different variable basically one `p` if it has multiple tags within then it should be split and save into different variables. If I know how can I get rest of text which are not in inner tags I can retrieve the rest.

I have written below: the below is returning just "return" which is in "'em' tags.
Here `ep` is basically `doc.select(p)`, selecting `p` tag and then iterating, not sure if I am doing right way, any other approaches are highly appreciated.

```
String text ="\<p><em>return </em>an item, cancel an order, print a receipt, track your purchases or reorder items.</p>"

Elements italic_tags = ep.select("em");
for(Element em:italic_tags) { 
 if(em.tagName().equals("em")) {
    System.out.println( em.select("em").text());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to select each sub text and text enclosed by different tags you need to try selecting `Node` instead of `Element`. I modified your HTML to include more tags so the example is more complete:

```
        String text = "<p><em>return </em>an item, <em>cancel</em> an order, <em>print</em> a receipt, <em>track</em> your purchases or reorder items.</p>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text);

        Element ep = doc.selectFirst("p");
        List<Node> childNodes = ep.childNodes();
        for (Node node : childNodes) {
            if (node instanceof TextNode) {
                // if it's a text, just display it
                System.out.println(node);
            } else {
                // if it's another element, then display its first
                // child which in this case is a text
                System.out.println(node.childNode(0));
            }
        }
```

output:

```
return 
an item, 
cancel
 an order, 
print
 a receipt, 
track
 your purchases or reorder items.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this gave me some idea, but my use case is it will have more than one tag for same text , let's say,  <p> <em>return</em> <strong><em>an item</em></strong> <u>cancel</u> </br></p> something like this, the code will work for only childnodes, what if I have multiple childnodes within a childnode

Comment: You can loop over every child of `.childNodes()` and then for each of them also search all `.childNodes()`. Create recursive function to do this until there's no more children or until it finds ` instanceof TextNode`.

Comment: Thank you So much for your response!

Comment: Hi, Have another question, This is for line break element, I need to get  response as "test line break" if I am reading this node "<br/> test line break." how to get this? I tried below but it is splitting into text and returning both as different values

String line_break ="<p><br/> test line break.</p>";  
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line_break);
  Elements para_tags = doc.select("p");   
  for (Element e : para_tags) {
   System.out.println(para_tags);
   List<Node> childNodes = e.childNodes();
   for (Node node : childNodes) {
    System.out.println(node);
   }
  }

Comment: Try selecting and removing every `<br>` using `doc.select("br").remove();`